# Certificate Validation Failure (Cisco)

Tags: server, vpn, ssl, cisco

Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client throws an error when trying to connect to the server.

I got the certificate name2019.pfx, then converted it to files: someName.pem someName1.key comeName2.crt. I initially added someName.pem someName1.key to the /opt/.cisco/certificates/client and /opt/.cisco/certificates/client/private folders. Then tried to connect to the server, but nothing worked.

After that, he also added all three files to the folder "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/" and then executed the command "sudo update-ca-certificates", then also tried to connect, but nothing came of it.

Tell me what I'm doing wrong. Already spent a lot of time on it!

P.S. Also I added a certificate to Mozilla FireFox & Chrome.

[image]

Comment: The *exact* error messages you are seeing will be helpful here.  Also which Cisco product are you trying to use this for?

Comment: cisco version 4.6.03049

Comment: No, I mean, there are ***five thousand Cisco products***.  What specific Cisco product is this for?  VPN client?  some other authentication mechanism?

Comment: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client

Comment: That client should have a log, but if the issue is cert validation failure, then the issue is between the certs you received and the configuration in use.  Namely, that the cert served up does NOT match the cert that it's expecting, and that means you typically have to reach out to the server provider for the proper configuration details.

Comment: You probably do not have imported cert correctly. Try use this configuration: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/214612-configure-anyconnect-secure-mobility-cli.html